# bottom sheet does not come in front of linear layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

How to make this bottomsheet come in front not below.
The BottomSheet is placed in Coordinator Layout below in the root linearlayout.
Since Stackoverflow is not allowing me to more code I'm adding screenshots.
Any help is appreciated.

[Bottom Sheet does not swipes up and stays under](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVy2h.png)

[This is my bottomsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0d6g.png)

My main activity xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/backgroudColor"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150sp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:id="@+id/relative">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:text="30"
                android:textSize="62sp"

                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/weekDay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Monday"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/date"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/date"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"

                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dateMonthYear"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="January 2016"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/date"
                android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="#e74c3c"
            android:id="@+id/fajar">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Fajar"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="#2ecc71"
            android:id="@+id/zuhar">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Zuhar"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="#3498db"
            android:id="@+id/asar">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Asar"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="#9b59b6"
            android:id="@+id/maghrib">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Maghrib"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="#f1c40f"
            android:id="@+id/isha">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Isha"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"/>


        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/backgroudColor">

            <include layout="@layout/bottomsheet"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That is because of linear layout orientation vertical. Try to use relative layout or make scroll view your parent layout to see bottom sheet placement in xml

Comment: have a look at this article- https://medium.com/android-bits/android-bottom-sheet-30284293f066

Comment: @Lucky Hi thanks for answering. Since the items(5) are fixed should I really use scrollview? and how can I achieve the same result in relative layout? Does it allow nesting of LinearLayouts in parent Relative Layout? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/app_background"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150sp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:id="@+id/relative">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:text="30"
                android:textSize="62sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/weekDay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Monday"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/date"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/date"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dateMonthYear"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="January 2016"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/date"
                android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="#e74c3c"
            android:id="@+id/fajar">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Fajar"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="#2ecc71"
            android:id="@+id/zuhar">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Zuhar"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="#3498db"
            android:id="@+id/asar">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Asar"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="#9b59b6"
            android:id="@+id/maghrib">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Maghrib"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="#f1c40f"
            android:id="@+id/isha">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Isha"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/bottomsheet"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Try this xml code and importantly dont forget to add layout_behavior attribute to the bottomsheet.xml .

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
android:elevation="1dp"
```

to bottomsheet's layout xml.

Comment: No visual difference at all

Comment: I have tried with elevation that is working totally fine.. if you have given elevation to any parent layout then try increasing elevation.